# how can I call a method that is inside of Component? (I can't pass this method in props)

Tags: reactjs

this seems like a duplicate question but it is not, the examples I have seen explain how to pass a function through props.

I have three components: `ComponentA`, `ComponentB` and App (App is the component root). I want to call a function contains in `ComponentA` using a button that is inside of `ComponentB`.

```
import "./styles.css";
import ComponentA from "./componentA";
import ComponentB from "./componentB";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <ComponentA>
          <ComponentB />
        </ComponentA>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

const ComponentA = ({ children }) => {
  const hello = () => {
    alert("hello");
  //In my real scenario, this method contains a big logic...
  };
  return (
    <>
      Component A<div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
};

const ComponentB = () => {
  const callComponentAFunction = () => {
    // I need call "hello()" from ComponentA
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={callComponentAFunction}>
        Call function from ComponentA
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

How can I call `hello()` (function inside of `ComponentA`) from `ComponentB`?

[this is my live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tdd-wlo1e)

Comment: Just curious: Is there any reason you can't pass the function as props? Nonetheless, since you're wrapping ComponentB in ComponentA you could potentially use context in component A and leverage 'useContext' in component B. Having said that, this it is overkill to use context if you can just pass the function in as a prop

Comment: Is the function uses values from component A? If yes, you can't use it in another component without passing it in the props, because in the other component you don't have the values. If no, just move the function outside the component.

Comment: @adrian "Is there any reason you can't pass the function as props" can you give me please an example please? how can pass hello in the props using my structure?

Comment: You could define the function up to your App component (like @fullstack suggests), instead of defining it in ComponentA and pass it to Component B from App. Alternatively you can just call component B from Component A and pass in the function as props. If you can maybe elaborate on the requirements of the structure we can help more

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in many ways. Pass that function as props from component A.

Working example [Modified code](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-oskar-0453n?file=/src/componentA.js)

```
//App.js
import "./styles.css";
import ComponentA from "./componentA";
// import ComponentB from "./componentB";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <ComponentA />
      </>
    </div>
  );
}


//Component A
import ComponentB from "./componentB";

const ComponentA = ({ children }) => {
  const hello = () => {
    alert("hello");
  };
  return (
    <>
      Component A<div>{children}</div>
      <ComponentB hello={hello} />
    </>
  );
};

export default ComponentA;

//Component B
const ComponentB = ({ hello }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={hello}>Call function from ComponentA</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default ComponentB;
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I can't mix componentB inside componentA.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the `React.Children.map`, the example like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-ellis-ksgkd?file=/src/componentB.js

Comment: it works, but can you explain me this part please? `          React.cloneElement(child, {
            hello
          })`

Comment: It means that use the  `React.cloneElement` to create a new Component, and you can give it some custom props like your hello to it

Comment: thanks crack!! a last question, how can typing that part, I am getting typing error using typescript over `child` :  `No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactPortal | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.`

Comment: may be you should declare the type of `child`, It seem like the React don't ensure the type of the  children ,and when you use the `React.cloneElement` ， the child should be a ReactNode，you should meke sure the children  from props may not be a  ReactNode